# How to get path of button located in table cells

Tags: javascript, html

[image]I am working on one table, where I have created one button which I am using in different rows and tables based on some condition. 
I have one scenario where I need to show the button to some specific users, I have implemented the condition however I am not able get the path of the button, I can hide the cell but in that case complete cell is removed from the table which is not looking good, please help me to get the path of the button, so that I can hide it, here is the code I am using:

```
  totalrows = document.getElementById("DEVmyTable").rows.length;

  for(i = 0;i<totalrows; i++){


  if(actualusernamevalue == currentusernamevalue){

  table.rows[i].cells[6].style.display = "";
  }
  if(actualusernamevalue != currentusernamevalue){

  table.rows[i].cells[6].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Here in Cells[6] my button is present which I am created dynamically like this:

```
row = document.getElementById("DEVFirstrow");
var w = row.insertCell(6); 
w.innerHTML = '<button onclick="Releaseentry(this)"type="button" 
id="release" class="btn btn-primary release">Release</button>';
```

I have not added the complete code here, but based on the ids I am using this code in different table and rows.

in this code I have hidden the cell, for hiding the button I am not able to get the path, and that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have got my solution finally, Thanks @natan for your help.

```
 table.rows[i].cells[6].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].style.display = "none";

 table.rows[i].cells[6].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].style.display = "";
```

I should have used this code.

Answer (score 1):

You actually style the cell based on table.rows[i].cells[6].style.display and not its content. You choose the 6th cell and style it.Another mistake you make is that you use id in the button while the button is used in multiple rows which makes the id useless as it should be unique.
What I would do is simply use the class of the buttons and then based on the checks you have decide what the button should do using jquery, so:

if(actualusernamevalue == currentusernamevalue){

```
 $('.release').show();
```

}
  if(actualusernamevalue != currentusernamevalue){

```
$('.release').hide();
```

}

If I understand well what you are trying to do at least. The simpler solution, the better solution!

EDIT: By the way, you should keep in mind that if someone wants to find the button when you play with the display property in both ways, they can always find it through the source code. If someone inspects the element and changes the CSS manually they will be able to see the button, so it's always important to have back end validation too for cases like this.

Comment: Your first point will not work here, actually firstly I apologize, I am not using button id for hiding my button,  I think you have misunderstood my question, here this button with same class display in each row.. and in each row some button may belongs to some other user and some buttons may belongs to current user , so according to my condition id any release button belongs to some other user then it will not be displayed to current user, in you case, if I will use your code it will hide all button together or display all button based on the users

Comment: your second point is absolutely right, any user can change the css manually and display the button for himself,  but if any user will do it then there is another check in the backend for user verification so yes he will be able to see the release button but will not be able to perform any action.

Comment: But you use the same code to render the button in each row, right? If yes, then you render multiple buttons with the same id. If not, then my first comment was related to the previous thought so ignore it. So, if understand well now you have multiple buttons in a singe cell too except from the release button which is in many rows? Do these have the same class too?

Comment: Yes its a single element having same class and I am using it in multiple rows, I also have updated the screenshot of some part of my table, you can refer that screenshot as well..

Comment: in this screenshot, where the release button is not displayed that row actually does not belong to the current user.

Comment: OK so it's one button in each cell and each row as I understood, why isn't the jquery code working? what is the issue?

Comment: Your jquery code is impacting all buttons together, and I am not getting the expected result.